How to evaluate this definite integral in terms of Bessel functions.
In the context of Green's functions for the Free Klein-Gordon field, the following integral occurs:
$$\int_m^{\infty}{\rho e^{-\rho r}\over\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}}\; d\rho.$$ Here $m$, is a positive constant in the set of real numbers. One may write:
$$\begin{align}\int{\rho e^{-\rho r}\over\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}}\;d\rho &=\int 2e^{-\rho r}{d\over d\rho}\bigg(\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}\bigg)\;d\rho\cr &=2e^{-\rho r}\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}+\int2re^{-\rho r}\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}\;d\rho,\end{align}$$
however, the integral
$$\int e^{-\rho r}\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}\;d\rho;$$
has stumped me. So, how to evaluate:
$$\int_m^{\infty}e^{-\rho r}\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}\;d\rho?$$
I have been told that the integral can be evaluated in terms of Bessel function, however, I  would like to know and understand the steps involved in getting from the integral to the specific Bessel functions. Thanks or your time and consideration.

try $\rho=\cosh(u)$ or something similar

Substitute $u=\frac{\rho}{m}$, this gives
$$ \int_m^{+\infty}\frac{\rho e^{-\rho r}}{\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}}d\rho=\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{mue^{-rmu}}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}du. $$
Now, substitute $v={\rm argch}(u)$, this gives you
$$ \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{mue^{-rmu}}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}du=m\int_0^{+\infty}{\rm ch}(v)e^{-rm{\rm ch}(v)}dv=mK_1(rm) $$
where
$$ K_{\alpha}(x)=\int_0^{+\infty}{\rm ch}(\alpha x)e^{-x{\rm ch}(t)}dt $$
is a modified Bessel function.

Merci beaucoup pour l'aide.

Do you know how one can show that $$K_{\alpha}=\int_0^{\infty}ch(\alpha x)e^{-xch(t)}; dt?$$

@AlbertusMagnus It depends on what your initial definition of $K_{\alpha}$ is, I took this form as a definition.

I see. Do you know the motivation for the definition as you have given it?

$K_{\alpha}$ and $I_{\alpha}$ (which is another modified Bessel function) are two lineary independent solutions of the differential equation
$$ x^2y''+xy'-(x^2+\alpha^2)y=0 $$
so they span the set of solutions. They can be expressed with the usual $J_{\alpha}$ Bessel function. You can find more details and references here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1 including the proof of this integral formula.
